# Sign data with private key inside a truffle test file

Tags: truffle, testing

I've got a contract method that checks the signer of a message using the solidity [ecrecover](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/units-and-global-variables.html) function. In my truffle test file I now want to check if this is done correctly. Therefore I need to sign a message within the testfile using a private key.

Using this

```
let signedMessage = await web3.personal.sign("data", accounts[0])
```

does not work with error "Method personal_sign not supported."

Any idea how to do this? Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I went through exactly the same problem a couple of days ago and it seems that the personal_sign method is rarely exposed for security reason.

I sorted this out using a random private key and a JavaScript library called [ethereumjs-util](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-util)

```
var EthUtil             = require('ethereumjs-util');

const messageToSign = "hello world";
const privateKey = "43f2ee33c522046e80b67e96ceb84a05b60b9434b0ee2e3ae4b1311b9f5dcc46";

var msgHash = EthUtil.hashPersonalMessage(new Buffer(messageToSign));
var signature = EthUtil.ecsign(msgHash, new Buffer(privateKey, 'hex')); 
var signatureRPC = EthUtil.toRpcSig(signature.v, signature.r, signature.s)

console.log(signatureRPC);
```

That returns:

> 0xd74a20b5a5b58185cc701e9d1349f240ff04154ab600266748bd45986104f0a62b8b827e2ba4a0da018efffb0ea16506503f4292538d791232ce574ac283e47c00

---

**Working Code is available [on my github](https://github.com/gjeanmart/stackexchange/tree/master/44735-sign-data-with-private-key-inside-a-truffle-test-file)**

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me! However, I replaced the random private key with the one generated by testrpc so that I can validate that the signer is actually accounts[0]. That is ok, but I need to do this every time I start a new testrpc process.

Comment: When you start testrpc, you can force it to use an account by default rather than autogenerate a new one all the time: `testrpc --account="0x0F0F0F0F0F%PRIVATE KEY%,10000000000000000000000%INITIAL BALANCE IN WEI%"  --secure -u 0` - [more info](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli)

Comment: @Greg Jeanmart Hi, I have a similar problem with `web3.eth.personal.sign` 
 and `web3.eth.sign` here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/52584/new-update-i-need-to-run-testrpc-signing-a-message-using-ethereumjs-abi But till now I could not solve this problem. Thank you

Comment: This works but curious as to why the hashes aren't the same when I use web.utils.sha3 - nor does it work without the hash function above?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to hardcode a private key or import a dependency. The accounts supplied by truffle+ganache are accessible in the web3.eth provider.

You can use `web3.eth.sign` to sign arbitrary data. It will hash the data using keccak256 and sign the hash. It is async so you have to await it, and it returns the 65-byte signature.

```
const sig = await web3.eth.sign(data, fromAccount)
const txSig = await web3.eth.signTransaction(tx, fromAccount)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you cannot use the addresses available under the `accounts` to sign, the best way is to create one (or more) address(es) using `web3.eth.accounts.wallet.create(x)` (where `x` = number of accounts you want to generate).

Within your truffle test, you can create the wallet in the `before(...)` hook, and reference the newly created address(es) to some globally scoped variables.

```js
contract("Your Contract", async (accounts) => {

    let firstAccount,
        secondAccount,
        thirdAccount

    before(async () => {
        await web3.eth.accounts.wallet.create(3) // create 3 accounts

        firstAccount = web3.eth.accounts.wallet[0]
        secondAccount = web3.eth.accounts.wallet[1]
        thirdAccount = web3.eth.accounts.wallet[2]
    })

    // tests here...

})
```

Each newly created address will have both property and method attach to them ([see web3 docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.4.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#wallet-add)):

- `privateKey` ([see example of returned object for `wallet.add` in web3 docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.4.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#id31))
- `sign(...)` ([see web3 docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.4.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#sign))

Both give you two ways to sign your message.

### via `web3.eth.accounts.wallet[...].sign(...)`

```js
let signature = web3.eth.accounts.wallet[firstAccount].sign("Message To Sign").signature
```

*or alternatively*

#### via [`web3.eth.accounts.sign(...)`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.4.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#sign), using `privateKey`

```js
let signature = web3.eth.accounts.sign("Message To Sign", firstAccount.privateKey).signature
```

**NB:** you can also use [object destructuring syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to extract the signature (from the object returned by both signing methods).
This also make the code shorter and a bit easier to read.

```js
// first method
let { signature } = web3.eth.accounts.wallet[firstAccount].sign("Message To Sign")

// second method
let { signature } = web3.eth.accounts.sign("Message To Sign", firstAccount.privateKey)
```