# Send funds locally

Tags: web3js

Can someone tell me how to send eth to the address locally? I tried to create an account, but I don’t know how to send funds to it locally

```
Web3 = require('web3');

web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545"));
console.log(web3.eth.accounts.create());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reference the web3.js docs around sending a transaction here:
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.4/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction

the example looks like:

```
// using the promise
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    from: '0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe',
    to: '0x11f4d0A3c12e86B4b5F39B213F7E19D048276DAe',
    value: '1000000000000000'
})
.then(function(receipt){
    ...
});
```

If the from account is not unlocked, you may need to either unlock it or sign the transaction.

Unlocking (results in security concerns)
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-personal.html#unlockaccount

Signing Raw Transaction:
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#sendsignedtransaction

**Example**

Step 1: Start ganache
[image]

Step 2: Init NPM project and npm install web3 (version 1.2.4 in this example)

Step 3: Write code (take addresses from ganache available accounts)

```
var Web3 = require('web3');

web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545"));

web3.eth.getBalance('0x9e5ef1c0a4b1619be3e83184a6549b5ee11a159c').then(console.log);

// using the promise
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    from: '0x557d3aec51e4461b52c504f087e7122c8906be6c',
    to: '0x9e5ef1c0a4b1619be3e83184a6549b5ee11a159c',
    value: '10000000'
})
.then(function(receipt){
  console.log(receipt.transactionHash);
  console.log("ending balance:");
  web3.eth.getBalance('0x9e5ef1c0a4b1619be3e83184a6549b5ee11a159c').then(console.log);
});
```

step 4: run code

[image]

Comment: i get an error `(node:7928) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid JSON RPC response:`

Comment: are you running ganache? if so what command are you using to start it? maybe try something more simple like getting the balance of an address to confirm your provider is set up correctly

Comment: Thanks for helping!  When I use the ganache-cli command at the end I have `Listening on 127.0.0.1:8545` and I can not use other code

Comment: do you have telegram?

Comment: no - but you can add another question or add more detail and i'd be happy to try to help

Comment: I enter the ganache-cli command, after which I get 10 accounts. How do I continue to work with these accounts? Are these accounts stored somewhere?

Comment: when you run `ganache-cli` you can use `-m "use your own mnemonic just a random set of words"` -- this will make it so you can get the same accounts / private keys every time. At this point I'll usually just hardcode the addresses / private keys as configs (this is insecure and just for dev purposes). You can also get accounts programmatically  `web3.eth.getAccounts().then((accounts) => console.log(accounts[0]));` According to this - https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/60995/how-to-get-private-keys-on-truffle-from-ganache-accounts you can get private keys too but never tried

Comment: And how can i create an ethereum address not locally, but through a browser, for example, when registering a user

Comment: web3.eth.accounts.create([entropy]); -- Generates an account object with private key and public key. https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-accounts.html