# Truffle default account private keys

Tags: truffle, private-key, truffle-test, test

Is there a way in truffle develop tests to access the list of private keys in the same way we can access the list of accounts?

Basically, for every contract I need to test, the truffle test contract begins like :

```
contract("Testing Public Pool",function(accounts){....}
```

"accounts" is an array with the 10 default accounts generated by truffle when running the "truffle develop" command.

But is there a similar array for the private keys (that are also displayed when running the command)? I know I could copy/paste them manually but it is kind of annoying....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are two possible solutions to this.

1. The first is to use `HDWalletProvider`

[https://www.npmjs.com/package/@truffle/hdwallet-provider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@truffle/hdwallet-provider%20%20You%20can%20configure%20it%20in%20your%20truffle-config.js)

You can configure it in your `truffle-config.js`

2. Second approach would be to use mnemonics as explained in this answer:

[How to get private keys on Truffle from Ganache accounts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/60995/how-to-get-private-keys-on-truffle-from-ganache-accounts)